# How to automatically generate a list of items from Word 2013 document in an appendix

Tags: microsoft-word, automation, microsoft-word-2013, append

I've been working on a standards document for a couple years now which has become quite lengthy. It's comprised mostly of explanation and example paragraphs interspersed with numbered requirements.

---

Example:

[image: Example of standards document layout]

---

I would like to create an appendix section at the end of this document which would simply be a list of all the requirements found throughout the document.

Since this is a living document which is updated regularly, I'm looking for a way to automate the generation of this appendix item, so if I make changes which change the renumbering, I won't have to cut and paste each requirement by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as I suspect, you want the autonumbering included in your appendix and easily updatable, but you don't want page numbers included, try this instead of the index approach that *Wes* suggests. Like that approach, it has the virtue of not requiring VBA.

At the location where you want the appendix, insert a custom table of contents that is based on just the paragraph style that you're using for requirements, and that excludes page numbers. In the **Table of Contents** dialog box, clear the **Show page numbers** check box, click **Options**, and then, in the list of styles, clear the numbers out of all the fields, and enter an appropriate TOC level in the field for  whatever paragraph style you used for your requirement paragraphs).

This way, if you add, delete, or remove requirement paragraphs, a simple update of the TOC will automatically update the numbering.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you could use the Index feature in Word:

HIGHLIGHT: The text you want to appear in your appendix.

CLICK: (On the top  ribbon) References

CLICK: Mark Entry

CLICK: Mark

CLICK: Close

You'll see an XE code that looks like this {XE"text you highlighted"}.

Go to: Wherever you want to create your appendix

CLICK: On that page

CLICK: Insert index

Your text should appear on this page.

You can continue to mark text throughout your document.
Go back to your index/appendix anytime and CLICK within it.

CLICK: Update index

Notes:

1. You can choose default index styles, and you can add any heading you want.. in your case "Appendix 1" or whatever.
2. You can work with the index manually, but all changes will disappear when you Update.
3. To update the index, CLICK within it then CLICK: Update Index
4. To show or hide the xe codes CLICK: ¶ in the Home ribbon
5. The index/appendix does not update automatically. You need to update as above.
6. Finally, a caution: Save your document as "Document name with xe codes" or something so you keep your original document without them. As with many Word tools, this one has a tendency to sometime go wacky and mess everything up, with no way to restore the original (that I know of). If that happens, it'll be kind of nice to have the original, uncorrupted version of your years of hard work!